# How to detect if a video track is present in another video

Tags: video, encoding, video-processing

I'm newbie to the video encoding world. I'm working on something and I want to get your thoughts about that.

I want to analyze a video and see if a another video track is present in that video. and get the time frame when this track video appears.

I wanted to make things simple and do that with the audio file instead of the video.

1. get the audio file from the video
2. analyze the audio file and get the time frame when the audio track appears.

So I want to know if you have any idea about any library which I can use to make this use case.

I'm open to Python, Go, NodeJs

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for sounds like what is usually referred to as digital fingerprinting.

There are a number of 3rd party SDK's etc but the most popular open source one I think is pHash: http://www.phash.org